# How do I append a percent sign to my chart values?

Tags: javascript, svg, google-visualization

I would like to know, how can I append a percent sign (%) to the numbers inside my chart? I have already the numbers, I just want to have the symbol **'%'** after the numbers.

My options:

```
var options = {
    title: '',
    format: '#,#%',
    fontSize: 12,
    hAxis: {
        suffix: '%',
        ticks: [
          {v: 0,f: '0%'}, 
          {v: 25,f: '25%'},
          {v: 50,f: '50%'},
          {v: 75,f: '75%'}, 
          {v: 100,f: '100%'}
        ]
    }, //Baixo
    vAxis: {
        title: '',
        fontSize: 16,
        format: '#%',
        maxValue: 100
    },
    isStacked: 'true',
    color: '#000',
    colors: ['#4747D1', '#C2C2F0', '#B9CAFF', '#FF9999', '#A32900'],
    legend: {
        position: 'top'
    }
};
```

[jsFiddle : My full code](http://jsfiddle.net/tiagopmc/jr59x/)

Comment: Divide by 100? What's not working?

Comment: I explained wrong... Edited..

Comment: I see that you've specified a suffix in your code that apparently does this. Again, what's not working? I've edited your question since you're not actually attempting to convert anything.

Comment: I edited my post to show my full code in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but...percent is just a one hundredth part of something, so you must divide your 'something' by 100...

## Edit

You've actually been pretty close to solution :) you should use `suffix` instead of `pattern`.
I updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jr59x/1/

Comment: I didnt explain it right. I want the symbol of pencetage '%'.

Comment: You can't, not the way you probably want it to work. There's no data type like 'percentage'. If you want the symbol '%' to appear, you need to use strings, just like it's done right now in here:
    `ticks: [{v: 0, f: '0%'}, {v: 25, f: '25%'}, {v: 50, f: '50%'}, {v: 75, f: '75%'}, {v: 100, f: '100%'}]},`

If you simply need to use it as percentage (for example you need to treat 54 like it was 54%), then you need to use the fractions (in this example, 0.54).

Comment: Where do you want the percentage signs to appear? I already see some in your `options` variable... If you actually want it in your "chart" then you'll need to post the relevant code...

Comment: This options works just for vaxis and haxis. I want to the symbol "%" inside the numbers in my chart.

Comment: Then please post some relevant code like Casey said, and maybe a fiddle.net example? We don't know where & how to modify your code, if we don't know how it looks like already :)

Comment: Ok. I thought that just the options was necessary. I have posted the chart. I will post all my code.

Comment: I saw your answer, It almost correct, but there is a bug when you pass your mouve over the vaxis (N,NE,S,SE) ):

Answer (score 1):

Change the `pattern` in your NumberFormat:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '##,##\'%'});
```

The `%` character converts the value to a percentage (so `0.5` becomes `50%`), which isn't what you want, so you have to escape it with `'%` (`'` is the escape character, which must be escaped, since the string uses single-quotes; alternatively you can use double-quotes for the string: `"##,##'%"`).

Comment: Its right, but if you see, there is a bug when you do that. The bug is when you pass the mouse over it, it shows a zero percentage

Comment: @user3813186, why is that a "bug"? It is a incremental bar, it begins with 0.00% and ends with 100.00% - naturally, if you hover the mouse before or over the very beginning of the bar, the tooltip will say 0.00%. What do you think that should be shown instead of 0.00%?

Comment: If you hover in the vaxis (  S , SE , N , NE ) , you will see the bug.It will show the "0,00%" and the color is not right.

Comment: Look at here: http://jsfiddle.net/jr59x/1/ 
The colors of the VAxis is not right.

Comment: @davidkonrad, the bug is that any values with a `0` will have their annotations on the axis instead of where they should be (see the "s" row of bars; example with background color changed to highlight the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/bE9qD/1/).

Comment: @user3813186, I thought it was about something different :( Can now see what you mean per asgallant's link!!

Comment: @davidkonrad yes, that is what I was trying to explain. Do you know how can I fix it?